# No sound and the Dummy Output ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I have tried all of the solutions listed online and none of them worked. When I have a freshly installed instance of Ubuntu 22.04, I noticed there is no sound.

lscpi:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake-U v1 4c Host Bridge/DRAM Controller (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SATA AHCI Controller
00:19.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 02a8
00:1e.3 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ab
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP LPC Premium Controller/eSPI Controller
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SMBus Host Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation PS5013 E13 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
```